# Not able to login on MySQL in AWS RDS using root

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, aws

I am trying to connect my MySQL RDS from EC2. Under security groups I have made sure permissions are in place.

```
$ mysql -h xxx.xyz.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -p
Enter password:
```

I am sure password is correct; because i reset it using AWS console. I am getting following error:

```
 Access denied for user 'root'@'ip-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal' (using password: YES)
```

Looks like

Comment: You say you have made sure permissions are in place; does that mean you added the EC2 instance's security group the the RDS instance's security group?

Comment: Yes Willem.. And I feel that will take care of allowing tcp connection between EC2 and RDS.. And root password should also be fine.. I guess that permissions at mysql level is creating problem !

Comment: As part of the setup process you are asked to choose a master username. Are you able to connect with that?

Comment: @Deepak what Willem is saying in the above comment is that there is no "root" user in RDS unless you chose "root" as the master username or manually created an account with that name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am 99% sure that Amazon RDS does not give you a 'root' access. i.e. You can't create a user as 'root'@'localhost' or 'root'@''.

Can you confirm user you have used while launching Amazon RDS instance? and make sure that Password matches with user created.

Comment: Security group does not matter here as you are able to connect to Amazon RDS and "Access denied ...." is authentication error due to wrong credentials specified while connecting to RDS/

Comment: I agree Mahesh it is not a problem of security group. Is there any way I can know this master user I used ?  I tried whatever users I could think of.

Comment: I have tried in Amazon RDS to find out Master user credentials, but could not find a useful link. I suggest you to terminate this instance and launch a new instance and note down Master user credentials ... otherwise contact Amazon RDS support and ask for details

Comment: right now the only way to find master user was using RDS tool.. which worked for me.

Comment: The default master username is `rdsadmin`.

Comment: Unbelievable, that was actually the solution.
removed special chars from password and reset it. It worked afterwards.

Comment: I am on situation where the username used during rds setup is not having permission to take backup so trying to find the master username but could not. Wondering now how do i give permission to the user.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a bug in AWS console. Most likely you've provided a password with restricted characters for the master user. In this case, AWS console doesn't prevent it, but you will never manage to connect to the database, even you'll change a password (BTW here AWS console will not allow you to insert restricted characters). The only way to cope with this issue is the redefinition of a new RDS instance/cluster (Definitely you can try to resolve it with the AWS support team)

P.S. Even though it was reported many years ago, the bug still exists there))

Comment: Hi, Welcome to the site and thanks for your answer. Do you happen to have a link documenting said bug in more detail?

Comment: It seems AWS is unaware of this bug, so no documenting